# Shiftable multiscale transform by Simoncelli et all, proof proposition 1.

Tags: fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, signal-processing

I'm reading through [enter link description here](http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/simoncelli_shift.pdf) this paper.
And I'm trying to understand the proof of the proposition 1, which states:

> The transformation defined by
>   $$
> y[n] = \int_{0}^{2\pi} dx h(n\Delta_x - x)f(x)
> $$
>   is shiftable if and only if there's a set of interpolation functions, $b_n(x_0)$ that satisfy the matrix equation
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> e^{jx_0k_0} \\
> e^{jx_0k_1} \\
> \vdots \\
> e^{jx_0k_{M-1}}
> \end{pmatrix} =
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & e^{j\Delta_x k_0} & e^{j 2 \Delta_x k_0} & & e^{j(N-1)\Delta_x k_0} \\
> 1 & e^{j\Delta_x k_1} & e^{j 2 \Delta_x k_1} & \ldots & e^{j(N-1)\Delta_x k_1} \\
> & \vdots & & \\
> 1 & e^{j\Delta_x k_{M-1}} & e^{j 2 \Delta_x k_{M-1}} & & e^{j(N-1)\Delta_x k_{M-1}}
> \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> b_0(x_0) \\
> b_1(x_0) \\
> \vdots \\
> b_{N-1}(x_0) \\
> \end{pmatrix} \;, \forall x_0
> $$

The paper proves such proposition. And I understand the proof. However the form of the linear system above doesn't seem to me depends from the $h$, and therefore to me it seems that for any $h$ we have a shiftable transformation.

PS. Shiftability means that for all $x_0$ we have

$$
 \int_{0}^{2\pi} dx h(x_0 - x)f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} b_j(x_0) y[n]
$$

Namely convolution can be expressed as interpolation of $N$ samples.
Notation in general of the paper is not entirely clear, for example Fourier series of $h(x)$ is denoted by $H(k)$, with a different variable, while to me the variable should be the same.

Comment: The interpolation functions $b_n$ that need to satisfy the equality are defined via $h$. So the linear system does depend on $h$.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point. If the system doesn't depend on h what's the point on giving conditions on h?

Comment: But the system does depend on $h$. That is my point.

Comment: Then please expound... Maybe with an answer

Answer (score 1):

The statement of the proposition continues after presenting the linear system. It continues by saying: "where $\{k_0, k_1, \dots, k_{M-1}\}$ is the set of frequencies for which $H(k)$, the Fourier series of $h(x)$, is nonzero". I guess that gives your dependence on $h$.

Comment: I'll read through the paper again.